# Point in zone problem in calculation

Tags: google-maps, point-in-polygon, geophp

I have a strange problem that i believe its because the zone pass through international date line.
My goal is to find if a point is within a zone and I use the geoPHP library, everything seems to be working properly expect on cases as the attached zone.
In attached image you can see the zone and the point, but when i check if the point is in zone i get true.

Any ideas about how to handle such cases ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All but one of the point in polygon libraries / routines that I've found fail on a polygon that includes the date line.

The all seem to use ray casting or other algorithms that wrap the wrong way or just simply don't work.

I believe that the routine in OGR works properly but it's somewhat complex to implement.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861196/check-if-a-geopoint-with-latitude-and-longitude-is-within-a-shapefile

or [look here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/How-to-identify-a-point-is-belong-to-a-polygon-td4989501.html)